# Python interpreter can't find face module although it is in the build directory of Opencv 3.0.0

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I was reading [this tutorial](http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html) and when I tried to run the attached face recognizer python code
it gave me the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

- I am on ubuntu 15.04, I have python 2.7, numpy, matplotlib and PIL installed and updated.
- I pulled the latest sources of opencv from http://github.com/itseez/openc..., compiled according to the documentation.I added the latest source of opencv contrib from https://github.com/Itseez/open..., compiled according to the documentation.

To make sure:

- I have the python bindings i typed the following in the python shell:

  import cv2
  cv2.**version**

it returned the following '3.0.0'

- The face module folder already in the modules folder in the build directory
- I modified the original code with my recent images database directory and haarcascade xml file and

  recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

to be

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

- When i tried to run type

  import cv2
  help(cv2.face)

it returned the following error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

- When I tried to explore this file: build/modules/python2/pyopencv_generated_types.h I found that:

  pyopencv_face_BasicFaceRecognizer_Type.tp_base = &pyopencv_face_FaceRecognizer_Type; pyopencv_face_LBPHFaceRecognizer_Type.tp_base = &pyopencv_face_FaceRecognizer_Type;
- I googled extensively to find a solution and I tried all the available solutions but still stuck at the same point. AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
- The last activity about the similar questions was from 7 month ago so I re-ask this question to figure out if there are new answers about this issue.

What should I do?

Comment: Read opencv's build steps for python wrappers carefully. Maybe you missed a flag in your configure step.